# Neo4j GraphRepository derived finder methods

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a problem with derived finder methods of GraphRepository.

**Short version:**

```
User foundUser1 = userRepository.findByEmail("test@gmail.com");
User foundUser2 = userRepository.findByPropertyValue("id", 1);
```

works, but not:

```
User foundUser3 = userRepository.findById(1);
```

**Long version:**

*test-context.xml*

```
<context:annotation-config/>    
<neo4j:config storeDirectory="data/graph.db" />
<neo4j:repositories base-package="com.blbl.repository"/>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/>
```

*UserGraphRepository.java:*

```
public interface UserGraphRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {
    public User findById(int id);
    public User findByEmail(String email);    
}
```

*User.java:*

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {
    @GraphId private Long nodeId;
    @Indexed(unique = true) private int id;
    @Indexed private String email;

    public User(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    // getter & setters
}
```

*Test:*

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"/test-context.xml"})
@Transactional
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserGraphRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private Neo4jTemplate template;


    @BeforeTransaction
    @Rollback(value = false)
    public void cleanDb() {
        Neo4jHelper.cleanDb(template);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSaveUser() {
        User user = userRepository.save(new User(1));
        user.setEmail("test@gmail.com");
        userRepository.save(user);

        User foundUser1 = userRepository.findByEmail("test@gmail.com");
        User foundUser2 = userRepository.findByPropertyValue("id", 1);
        User foundUser3 = userRepository.findById(1);
        assertThat(foundUser1, is(notNullValue())); // SUCCESS
        assertThat(foundUser2, is(notNullValue())); // SUCCESS
        assertThat(foundUser3, is(notNullValue())); // FAILS
    }
}
```

third assert fails since foundUser3 is null. I don't understand why this is happening while it can find with `findByPropertyValue("id" ..)`. I wonder if **id** is some sort of keyword? (Note that my `@GraphId` is called `nodeId`)

PS:

```
<neo4j-version>1.8.M07</neo4j-version>
<org.springframework.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
<org.springframework-data-neo4j.version>2.1.0.RC3</org.springframework-data-neo4j.version>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an issue with special indexing of numeric fields. I raised an issue here: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAGRAPH-294

Comment: I guessed derived finders uses findByPropertyValue behind the scenes but it's not the case apparently. Thanks

Comment: no they generated cypher queries, findByPropertyValue is just a simple index lookup, derived finders are/can be much more complex