# Spring - @Autowiring A Repository Does Not Work. @Autowiring Other Classes Does

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, autowired, spring-data-neo4j

I am attempting to autowire a repository and it refuses to work. I have been struggling with this for a week now and i cannot seem to figure it out. What is funny is that when i comment out the autowiring of the person repository the program works and compiles correctly but as soon as I attempt to autowire the person repository i get this error (i have omitted most of the error because I cannot post all of it) Here is the exception, my classes are below it.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.mycompany.smsdatabase.service.PersonImport com.mycompany.smsdatabase.controller.HomeController.personImport; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personImport': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mycompany.smsdatabase.repositories.PersonRepository com.mycompany.smsdatabase.service.PersonImport.PersonRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.mycompany.smsdatabase.repositories.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here are the classes I am working with.

```
package com.mycompany.smsdatabase.controller;

import com.mycompany.smsdatabase.service.PersonImport;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
   @Autowired
   PersonImport personImport;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Home()
    {
      personImport.doImportPerson("anthony");
      return "index";
    }
}

package com.mycompany.smsdatabase.service;
import com.mycompany.smsdatabase.domain.Person;
import com.mycompany.smsdatabase.repositories.PersonRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonImport  {

@Autowired
private PersonRepository PersonRepository;

 public Person doImportPerson( String id)
 {   
  Person person = PersonRepository.findById(id);
  if (person == null) {
    person = new Person(id,"anthony");
     }
   PersonRepository.save(person);
     System.out.println("inside doImportPerson");
     return person;
 }
}
package com.mycompany.smsdatabase.repositories;

import com.mycompany.smsdatabase.domain.Person;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person>{
    Person findById(String id);
}
```

I have omitted the person class since it is simply a node entity class.

Also Here is my Application context xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.smsdatabase">
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:spring-configured/>
    <neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/data/graph.db"/>
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.smsdatabase"/>

    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.test.ImpermanentGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for PersonImport please?

Comment: Nevermind, I missed it the first time.

Comment: can you put PersonRepository implementation there also? At least the class declaration with the annotations

Comment: Do you have an implementation of the PersonRepository interface?  Looks like it can't find it.  The @Repository annotation should be on a concrete class.  And then you should inject the interface.

Comment: No I was under the impression that the all i had to do was make a PersonRepository interface, extend the GraphRepository and then could autowire the repository into my classes. Is there something else that needs to be done first?

Comment: In this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334708/neo4j-graphrepository-derived-finder-methods, It does not appear that the interface is annotated w/@Repository.

Comment: I have tried it wihtout the @Repository annotaiton as well sitll doesnt work

Comment: I noticed that in the context xml you declared *com.mycompany.smsdatabase* as repositories base package, whereas the actual package in the code you attached is *com.mycompany.smsdatabase.repositories*.

Comment: @remigio I changed it to com.mycompany.smsdatabase.repositories, still no luck....

Comment: Still getting the same error messages or different ones?

Comment: Also, try to add *<context:annotation-config/>* to your application context xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Your spring config is wrong:

You have  `<neo4j:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.smsdatabase"/>` in your config

but the import in your java code reads

`import com.mycompany.smsdatabase.repositories.PersonRepository;`

You should correct your spring config to

`<neo4j:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.smsdatabase.repositories"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You should define corresponding beans for the variables annotated with @AutoWired in the application context file, i.e.

```
<bean id="personRepository" class="com.mycompany.smsdatabase.repositories.PersonRepository"/>
<bean id="personImport" class="com.mycompany.smsdatabase.service.PersonImport"/>
```

Comment: I have tried this and it still throws the same errors, im not sure what to do at this point

Comment: `PersonRepository` is an interface.

Comment: An interface cannot be autowired? in the cineast tutorial that spring provides they autowire many interfaces

Comment: @IceNine You don't autowire the interface, because the interface cannot be instantiated. You autowire the implementation to the interface. With a bean declaration as in this answer, Spring will try to instantiate `PersonRepository` which it cannot.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You're right, I missed *PersonRepository* is an interface. I think you can just remove the *PersonRepository* bean declaration, I've a similar project and everything is fine with repositories autowiring.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What IDE are you using, im using netbeans and it seems that spring isnt very friendly with netbeans

Comment: @IceNine I'm on Eclipse. The IDE shouldn't be an issue. Have you tried what I suggested below?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolisYeah i tried it didnt work, idk what happened to the answer though